# Need a Solution for file conversion in progress 4GL from .htm to .xlsx format

Tags: progress-4gl

I have to load a .htm file and save it to .xlsx file format by automation using progress? Need a solution to solve this!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nothing in Progress that will help you do this. If I had to do this, I'd look to Apache POI, which is capable of creating .xlsx fairly cleanly and has a reasonable learning curve, although it is picky about data coming into it and its error messages are typically obtuse. Using Progress directly, you could parse the .html (painfully), but creating .xlsx yourself is probably unrealistic. So, I'd also hunt around for any tools that can do this directly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What O/S and Progress version are you using?

If the HTML is well-formatted, perhaps you could use XML parsing to assist.  I have never tried this, though.

As for writing an Excel document, there are many approaches.  If you are running on a Windows box that has Excel on it, there are solutions that allow you to call the Excel libraries from inside of Progress.  If you need something portable, your choices are fewer.  We use [ABL_xks.i](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ablxlsi/), which works under both Linux and Windows.  It uses the native libraries under Windows, and produces an Excel XML spreadsheat under Linux.

As I recall, there exists a library that allows you to edit an OpenOffice template (Word or Excel) from within Progress.  (I would have to go searching for this, but a good place to start looking might be the [OpenEdge Hive](http://www.oehive.org)).  And there several commercial packages (especially report generators) that range from using the OO template technique to full automation of Excel output.

If this doesn't point you in the right direction, fill us in with some more details about what you want to do.